# I want to update my machine with VS2010 and SQL Server Express 2008 R2

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, installation

I'm currently using VS2008 with SQL Server Express 2005 with great success. I got all the bits to install VS2010 and SQL Server 2008 Express R2, and plan to tackle this over a weekend. My question is this:

What is the best approach to update my system to the latest bits. I'd *like* to uninstall VS2008 and SQL Server 2005 completely and just use the latest technologies. However, I don't want all the leftover fluff after install and would like to be able to know that things are going to go as planned (although they seldom do). Ultimately I want a clean configuration to get up to date with the latest and greatest stuff.

Could anybody see a problem with this process:

1. Uninstall SQL Server 2005
2. Uninstall VS2008
3. Install VS2010
4. Install SQL Server 2008 R2

I've searched all over the internet for tips on how to approach this. Most everything that I'm finding are the problems that people have when doing this. However, that's typically what the internet is for; when you have problems. So I'm reading everything with that in mind. :) I was going to "just do it", but figured it might be best to post the question out here to see if anybody has suggestions or tips for this process.

I'd appreciate any comments. Of course, I'll update this post once I've completed the steps so future geeks can benefit from my findings (good || bad).

Comment: Anecdote - we've done those steps in that order on 5 machines, and on four of them it worked flawlessly. On the 5, the antivirus had removed a file (exe) necessary for updating protected system files, and once that was fixed, the rest went smoothly.

Comment: Its not really a programming question though (even though programmers might be interested) This would be better on superuser.com

Comment: Great news! Did you uninstall all the additional components as well? Thanks for the comment. It gives me more confidence. :)

Comment: Yeah, we uninstalled everything VS and SQL related before installing the new versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question because nobody else did... Perhaps this was a poorly formatted question.

Regardless, I followed the steps outlined in my initial question and had a few nuances along the way.

1. After upgrading my ASP.NET MVC application to .NET 4.0 Framework doesn't allow me to debug anymore.
2. I had to jump through hoops to reference `System.Core` in order to allow my Linq queries to work again.
3. Cannot manage SQL Server Express 2008 R2 databases from 2008 Management Studio; it only lets me manage old SDF files.
4. Had to Reinstall JetBrains Resharper (not a big deal, but a nuance none-the-less).

Other than that, I'm very pleased with how easy the process was. I still need to figure our the ASP.NET debugging issue, and plan to update this answer once I do...

Answer (score 0):

You can just save yourself some time and install VS2010 and SQL2008 side by side with the current versions you have - they co-exist nicely.

Comment: I understand that. However, I don't need (or want) VS2008 or SQL Server 2005 once I've installed VS2010 and SQL Server 2008.